# How to prevent console applications from auto-closing in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, console

This has been pretty persistent and annoying issue that I could not resolve.
Namely, whenever I open console application (from .exe), console window is shrank and automatically closed within few seconds. For example, I've downloaded sys internals suite from microsoft website and some of these apps are console apps. Whenever I tried to open whois64.exe, it automatically closes and it is pretty much same with any other console app.
How can I resolve this issue? (Windows 8.1)

Comment: All programs run then exit (or crash). **(1)** The difference between a console program and a graphical program is a flag in the header of the disk file. If set Windows creates a console window for the program unless it was started by a console program in which case it will attach to the parent's console. If not set Windows does nothing. **(2)** The rules for consoles are that when the last program attached to the console exits the console will close. Most , but not all, console programs are designed to be used from a console shell - `cmd.exe`.

Comment: **(3)** Console and graphical programs are programmed to different models  But this is not enforced by Windows. **(4)** Services are usually console programs as they are invisible. A graphical program may generate a dialog box (eg  a message box) but noone can see it to click `Ok`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is normal behavior. Those applications are not getting closed – they are exiting on their own and doing exactly what they were written to do.

Sysinternals console-based tools are *not interactive* – they expect the information to be provided upfront through the command line. They were not programmed to ask for it through further prompts; when you run them with empty command line, they're programmed to only print some help text and immediately exit.

(So even if the console window didn't disappear when the program exited, you'd only be seeing the help text and could do nothing with it anyway.)

In other words, the program wasn't supposed to be run by double-clicking; it has to be run *from* a console shell (i.e. through Command Prompt or PowerShell) together with the input, e.g.:

```
.\whois64.exe superuser.com
```

If you want to make a double-clickable shortcut to the program for convenience, you'll need to use a wrapper that asks for the necessary information, runs the program, then waits (to hold the window open). For example, `whois64.bat`:

```
@set /p input=Enter the domain name: 
@whois64.exe %input%
@pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you want is to click the addressbar when you are in explorer seeing the exe such that you can type in it. (click on an empty white place) There, type in `cmd` and hit enter.

A command prompt opens in that location.

Now type in the name of the .exe file and you can see what it says without closing.